# Apache CXF: Why does putting cxf logging on my jax-ws endpoint fix this issue?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm seeing an  intermittent error like the following:

```
checkException (UnexpectedServiceExceptionCheckImpl.java:35) - An unexpected exception was found from source=[DesignService.generate] type=[class javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException] message=[Unmarshalling Error: [was class java.io.IOException] Strange I/O stream, returned 0 bytes on read ]: 
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: [was class java.io.IOException] Strange I/O stream, returned 0 bytes on read 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
    at $Proxy146.generate(Unknown Source)
```

I have MTOM enabled and I'm sending megabytes of data.

As soon as I add this to the endpoint, it fixes the issue:

```
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
```

Really? I find it hard to believe that forcing the logging would fix an unmarshalling problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WOW.  That is a bizzare one.   Is there any way to create a small test case that shows this and attache to a JIRA?    I'm really not even sure where to start looking with that on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My next step is taking a TCP dump and seeing if I can get more answers. If this doesn't give me any info, I'll try making a JIRA issue.

Comment: @stevebot or Daniel, did you ever find a solution for this?  We are having a very similar issue, take a look at this post: [“IOException: Strange I/O stream” in CXF service client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198778/ioexception-strange-i-o-stream-in-cxf-service-client).

Comment: @JohnLeehey we switched CXF versions and that fixed out problem. It was at my last job however so I no longer remember what version we switched to.