# "IOException: Strange I/O stream" in CXF service client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

We are seeing an intermittent error in CXF.  The response is fairly large (several hundred KB), MTOM is enabled, and enabling DEBUG for the CXF request/response logging interceptors fixes the issue, similarly to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902048/apache-cxf-why-does-putting-cxf-logging-on-my-jax-ws-endpoint-fix-this-issue) (which is unresolved).  Our project is leveraging CXF version 2.2.9.

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: [was class java.io.IOException] Strange I/O stream, returned 0 bytes on read 
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:146)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy751.browseFiles(Unknown Source)
…
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [was class java.io.IOException] Strange I/O stream, returned 0 bytes on read
                at com.ctc.wstx.util.ExceptionUtil.throwRuntimeException(ExceptionUtil.java:18)
                at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwLazyError(StreamScanner.java:731)
                at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.safeFinishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3657)
                at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getTextCharacters(BasicStreamReader.java:830)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleCharacters(StAXStreamConnector.java:323)
…
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
                ... 51 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Strange I/O stream, returned 0 bytes on read
                at com.ctc.wstx.io.BaseReader.reportStrangeStream(BaseReader.java:148)
                at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.loadMore(UTF8Reader.java:373)
…
```

I initially thought this was caused by a bad/invalid character (encoding?) in the response data; however, it is now looking more like a network issue.  It is very odd, the service has been operating for a long time (years) without issue prior to running into this problem.

Why does this error occur?  Is there a way to resolve this without enabling debug logging?

Answer (score 2):

Likely an upgrade to a newer version of CXF may fix this.   There were some bugs in the CXF mime streams.   In particular, this looks very similar to:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3068

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319395/what-0-returned-by-inputstream-read-means-how-to-handle-this) and considering the source code of [com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.loadMore](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.5/com/ctc/wstx/io/UTF8Reader.java#UTF8Reader.loadMore%28int%29), the problem is possible when the buffer passed to [mBuffer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.5/com/ctc/wstx/io/BaseReader.java#BaseReader.0mBuffer) through [BaseReader(ReaderConfig, InputStream, byte[], int, int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.5/com/ctc/wstx/io/BaseReader.java#BaseReader.%3Cinit%3E%28com.ctc.wstx.api.ReaderConfig%2Cjava.io.InputStream%2Cbyte%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29) is zero length.

Is the [loadMore()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.5/com/ctc/wstx/io/UTF8Reader.java#UTF8Reader.loadMore%28int%29) method implementation correct? Should they do that if [read()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/InputStream.java#InputStream.read%28byte%5B%5D%29) return 0?